# ASP.NET - Can I write my own messages to ETW?

Tags: asp.net, trace, etw

With the ASP.NET Events ETW (Event Tracing for Windows) provider, can I write custom messages to the trace from an ASP.NET page?

Answer (score 1):

You can use ETW infrastructure from .Net to fire your custom ETW events, have a look at:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tracing.EventSource/

or if you are using .Net 4.5 or above

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.tracing.eventsource.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered utilizing the ASP.NET [Tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y13fw6we%28VS.71%29.aspx) functionality?

**WEB.CONFIG**

```
<configuration>
 <system.web>
  <trace enabled="true" requestLimit="40" localOnly="false"/>
 </system.web>
</configuration>
```

**CODE TO CREATE TRACE MESSAGE**

```
Trace.Warn("TITLE", "TEXT/COMMENT");
```

---

It appears that this may be possible.  Read this info from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264809%28VS.100%29.aspx).  Specifically, it appears that you would use the Windows Performance Analyzer (WPA).

Further Reading:
*  [MSDN: How To Use Custom Performance Counters from ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms979204.aspx)
*  [MSDN: Performance Counters for ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fxk122b4%28VS.71%29.aspx)

Comment: I think that this answer is orthogonal to the question being asked.  This answer is better suited as a comment to the question.  The question is very specific about ETW tracing - it has nothing to do with the ASP.NET trace feature.

Answer (score 0):

A native (Win32) application can write Event Tracing for Windows (ETW) messages. Therefore .NET applications can, but it might require an adapter layer or significant work with P/Invoke to achieve it.

Three (possibly) relevant articles from MSDN Magazine are [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dvdarchive/cc163437.aspx), [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/magazine/ee412263.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/magazine/ee358703.aspx).

There is some information about ETW events from the .NET Framework itself [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee517330(VS.100).aspx).

[*This is work in progress for me.*]